# How to install libxcb

Tags: dpkg

I'm trying to install [Awesome's dependencies](https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/documentation/01-readme.md.html), specificall `libxcb` (using Ubuntu 16.04.1). What I did is run:

```
cd ~/Downloads
apt-get source libxcb
sudo apt-get build-dep libxcb
cd libxcb-1.11.1/
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

Is this the right procedure to build `libxcb`? Now I have a big list of `*.deb` files (see below). Which one should I install via `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`?

```
~/Downloads$ ls -a
.                                                libxcb-render0-dev_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
..                                               libxcb-res0_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
awesome-4.0                                      libxcb-res0-dbg_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
awesome-4.0.tar.xz                               libxcb-res0-dev_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb-1.11.1                                    libxcb-screensaver0_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb1_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb                libxcb-screensaver0-dbg_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.changes             libxcb-screensaver0-dev_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb_1.11.1-1ubuntu1.diff.gz                   libxcb-shape0_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb_1.11.1-1ubuntu1.dsc                       libxcb-shape0-dbg_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb_1.11.1.orig.tar.gz                        libxcb-shape0-dev_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb1-dbg_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb            libxcb-shm0_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb1-dev_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb            libxcb-shm0-dbg_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb1-udeb_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.udeb          libxcb-shm0-dev_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb-composite0_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb      libxcb-sync1_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb-composite0-dbg_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  libxcb-sync1-dbg_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb-composite0-dev_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  libxcb-sync-dev_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb-damage0_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb         libxcb-xevie0_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb-damage0-dbg_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb     libxcb-xevie0-dbg_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb-damage0-dev_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb     libxcb-xevie0-dev_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb-doc_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_all.deb               libxcb-xf86dri0_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb-dpms0_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb           libxcb-xf86dri0-dbg_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb-dpms0-dbg_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb       libxcb-xf86dri0-dev_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb-dpms0-dev_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb       libxcb-xfixes0_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb-dri2-0_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb          libxcb-xfixes0-dbg_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb-dri2-0-dbg_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb      libxcb-xfixes0-dev_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb-dri2-0-dev_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb      libxcb-xinerama0_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb-dri3-0_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb          libxcb-xinerama0-dbg_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb-dri3-0-dbg_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb      libxcb-xinerama0-dev_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb-dri3-dev_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb        libxcb-xkb1_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb-glx0_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb            libxcb-xkb1-dbg_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb-glx0-dbg_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb        libxcb-xkb-dev_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb-glx0-dev_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb        libxcb-xprint0_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb-present0_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb        libxcb-xprint0-dbg_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb-present0-dbg_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb    libxcb-xprint0-dev_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb-present-dev_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb     libxcb-xtest0_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb-randr0_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb          libxcb-xtest0-dbg_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb-randr0-dbg_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb      libxcb-xtest0-dev_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb-randr0-dev_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb      libxcb-xv0_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb-record0_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb         libxcb-xv0-dbg_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb-record0-dbg_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb     libxcb-xv0-dev_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb-record0-dev_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb     libxcb-xvmc0_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb-render0_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb         libxcb-xvmc0-dbg_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libxcb-render0-dbg_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb     libxcb-xvmc0-dev_1.11.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Do you have an ***excellent*** reason to build it manually instead of simply installing it from an existing repository?

Comment: @JuliePelletier No, if I tried `sudo apt-get install libxcb` I get `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libxcb
` And if I googled "install libxcb" I only find links they contains a installation from source.

Comment: The simplest solution I found which would probably work is: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:klaus-vormweg/awesome; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install awesome`

Comment: @JuliePelletier, which version do you install if you use the repo from klaus-vormweg?

Comment: Looking at the PPA's site, it would install version 4.0

Comment: @JuliePelletier I'm using ubuntu 16.04, I only find awesome 3.5 in the repo you mentioned https://launchpad.net/~klaus-vormweg/+archive/ubuntu/awesome.

Comment: Strangely, it seems like it was updated earlier today so you should check again.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The way you built `libxcb` is OK, but as [Julie Pelletier](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/167583/julie-pelletier) says you didn't need to build it from source.

The general approach in a case like this is to use `apt-cache search`; `apt-cache search libxcb` will list all the `libxcb`-related packages (and a few others which happen to mention `libxcb`) along with their short descriptions. You can then match these up with the [awesome requirements](https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/documentation/01-readme.md.html); assuming you're building the latter from source:

```
sudo apt-get install libxcb-randr0-dev libxcb-xtest0-dev libxcb-xinerama0-dev libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-xkb-dev
```

will install the required libraries and development files.

The [build dependencies](https://packages.debian.org/source/unstable/awesome) of the existing awesome package can serve as a useful guide to get started on the remaining dependencies.

Comment: If I run `apt-cache search libxcb` I got also a huge list of packages. Basically each package comes with 3 different types e.g. `libname`, `libname-dev` and `libname-dbg`. I see you mentioned to install only `*-dev`. What is the reason and when I need the other?

Comment: The reason is given in the packages' descriptions: the `-dev` packages contain the development files, which is what you need if you're building software that uses these libraries (which is your case). The `-dev` packages themselves depend on the library packages (which are needed to *run* software using the libraries), so you'll get those too automatically. You only need the `-dbg` packages if you want to debug the libraries (or see their details in stacktraces).

Comment: Thx alot, I don't know anymore why it looks that difficult for me :)